# Use predefined parameters into .ps1 file

Tags: parameters, teamcity

I have some .ps1 file which sets some variables. Variables are different derictories. I want to push predefined parameters to this variables. Looks like this

variables.ps1

> `$variable1="path/to/source"
>   $variable2="path/to/source/%teamcity.predefined.parameter%.pro
>   ...
>   $variableN="..."`

Build step read this file and set up this variables. But when i run build configuration, this variables are strings and next build steps didnt execute. Looks like teamcity doesnt "see" predefined parameters if they are set from file

build log looks like this

> [15:20:46] [Step 3/5] Cannot find file: D:\TEMP_WORK_DIR\PROJECT_PATH\%system.teamcity.projectName%.pro.

Is there is a way to solve that? I need that for dynamically usage of some files without rewriting .ps1 for each new %system.teamcity.projectName%

Answer (score 1):

replace in the file `%system.teamcity.projectName%` to `$Env:projectName`.

Crete build environment variable `projectName` and set value `%system.teamcity.projectName%`